# jquery works with .html page but not in .php page

Tags: php, html, jquery

**I am trying out this simple code on the server, jquery works as desired when i have test.html, but when i rename the page to test.php and run it the jquery is not functioning
**

## test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="script/jquery-3.6.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

</head>
<body>

    <div class="fhere">mysite</div>

    <script>
       $("fhere").text("mysite.com");
  
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

## test.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="script/jquery-3.6.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

</head>
<body>

    <div class="fhere">mysite</div>

    <script>
       $("fhere").text("mysite.com");
  
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

i have tried to place the script tag at the beginning of head tag in php page, but didn't help

Comment: Could you elaborate on "not functioning"? What exactly do you see? My first instinct is to guess that your server can't interpret php files, but without knowing exactly what you see, it's just a wild guess. Also I would replace `$("fhere").text("mysite.com")` with `$(".fhere").text("mysite.com")`

Comment: yeh sure, i am hosting on go daddy for reference.. the jquery gets executed when i load test.html page however when i load test.php which is having the same code jquery doesn't work or should i say the output isn't "mysite,com"..

Comment: So what's the output?

Comment: it's just showing my initial div which it :mysite". however the jquery script is supposed to turn the text to "mysite.com" which isn't happening

Comment: What happens if you replace `$("fhere").text("mysite.com")` with `$(".fhere").text("mysite.com")`. Note the dot before `fhere`.

Comment: such a dumb mistake i made, thanks for your time. however it's just a precursor to another problem i've been having with jquery, i've different webpage that is not loading jquery so i thought to test out with this simple code, thought maybe the problem was with ,php extension.. care to help?

Comment: Also remove `<script src="script/jquery-3.6.3.min.js"></script>`

Comment: If your php is executed, then the page will render after you fix your typo. You need to give us more information, like console errors or PHP errors (activate error handling) for us to help you with this. The code you provided will work if the backend supports PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace in `<script>`

```
  $( document ).ready(function () {
    let fhere =  $('.fhere');
    fhere.text("mysite.com");
  })
```